# EDIT/UPDATE comma separated values into mysql rows and add new

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic, mysqli

EDIT/UPDATE comma separated values into rows and add new

I am trying to edit products with ajax in different rows then update and add new rows from 
a form creating dynamic fields using the same name[]

but dont know how to pull them to edit them then update them in the same spot since they are in different rows and tables where i need updating

the only way i can think of editing them is like this example
http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-table-add-edit-delete-rows-dynamically-jquery-php/
but this is using the 1 row for every line and i have products in different rows

dont know if should edit them live like this, but how would i pull the old rows and add new rows as well linked to the same order
http://www.aquim.com/web-article-229.html

I was trying to edit them then update them something like, But how do i update the old products as well as adding new products and linking them to the different tables

EDIT FORM

product 1 [product 1 row] [price 1] [quanity 1] [total 1]

product 2 [product 2 row] [price 2] [quanity 2] [total 2]

then with a form add new products

```
<pre>`
  <form name="test" method="post" action="">
    <div id="container">
    <p id="add_field"><a href="#"><span>&raquo; Add New Bid</span>    </a></p>
    </div>
  </form>
 $('p#add_field').click(function(){
    count += 1;
    $('#container').append(
        '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' 
        + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder="Product Name" /><br />' 
        + '<input id="field_' + count + '" name="price[]' + '" type="text"  placeholder="Price"/><br />' 

        );

   });`
```

SELECT OLD PRODUCTS AND UPDATE THEN GET ID AND ADD NEW PRODUCTS AND LINK TO TABLE

The only way i thought about probably doing the updating is erasing everything and reinserting it but i assume that would cause a clash in the future if multiple people are doing it

```
             quotes TABLE 1
```

---

|    quoteID   |      bid_name   |     status    |      total    |

|------------------------------|

|   1 | bid1 |  pending  | 100 |

|   2 | bid2 |  stuff_y | 200 |

```
              quote_products_link TABLE 2
```

---

|    quoteID   |    productID  |
|------------------------------|

|   1          |     4         |

|   1          |     4         |

|   2          |     5         |

|   2          |     5         |

```
              quote_products_link TABLE 3
```

---

|    productID   |     product_name     |     price    |      quanity     |      bid_name  |

|   4  |     pro_1  |     price_1  |     quan_1        |     bid_1     |

|   4  |     pro_2  |     price_2  |     quan_2        |     bid_1     |

|   5  |     pro_3  |     price_3  |     quan_3        |     bid_2     |

|   5  |     pro_4  |     price_4  |     quan_4        |     bid_2     |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Pull --- Check --- Update --- Delete

Psudo Code, Non-working! This is to show the flow:

```
// Get the current database rows that are being edited
$results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM entries WHERE table_id=10');
$itemsInDB = [];
while($itemsInDB[] = mysql_fetch_row($results)) {}

// Iterate over the fields sent to the server
foreach($_POST['fields'] as $index=>$value) {
    // New Values that were submitted
    $field = $value;
    $price = $_POST['prices'][$index];

    // Get Rid Of Updated Rows From Pulled Array
    $found = false;
    foreach($itemsInDB as $dbindex=>$dbvalue) {
       // Check if the row exists in the database
       if ($dbvalue['field'] == $field) {
           $found = true;

           // Update the values that have changed
           if ($price !== $dbvalue['price'])
               UpdateDatabase('SET price=$price WHERE field=$field');

           // Remove the row from the pulled database rows
           array_shift($itemsInDB($dbindex,1);
       }
    }

    // insert it because it wasnt in the database
    if (!$found) 
       InsertDatabase('Values($field,$price)');
}

// Now that you have updated all the rows that were submitted
// The rows that are in the database that were not updated
// Need to be deleted because the user has removed them from the table
foreach($itemsInDB as $row) {
    $field = $row['field'];
    DeleteDatabaseRow('WHERE field='.$field.' LIMIT 1');
}
```

There may be a better way to do this... This is how I did it when I encountered this problem a while ago.

Comment: i am not sure i understand by databasegetrow do you mean, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Comment: I edited my post, By databasegetrow I meant all the rows that are associated with the HTML table that exist in the database. this edited version assumes that the inputs are name="fields[]" and name="prices[]". This method prevents having to delete all the data and reinsert, you can just update the changed values.

Answer (score 0):

to pull the products

```
$sqlString = "SELECT  
 GROUP_CONCAT(productID) AS id,
GROUP_CONCAT(productName) AS productsname,
GROUP_CONCAT(price) AS prices,
bidid FROM products GROUP BY bidid";

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   $currentbid[$row['bidid']][] = $row;
```

}

```
foreach ($currentbid as $bid => $itemList){

   foreach($itemList as $itemInfo => $loas){

 // count ids, by create a rande array or counting the wors
foreach(explode(",",$loas['id']) as $itemInfoss){

then inside the foreach - create the table rows

   $str.='<tr id="'.$itemInfoss.'"
```

to update them
depends on how you are updating them
I am updating them using the serialize function and some custom data

to get the ids, i use javascript to push them in an array

```
  mysqlrow.push($js(this).attr('data-rowid'));
```

to delete them first

```
   if(!empty($deleteoldproductsfrom)){

                foreach($erasecount as $deleteold){

                 $deleteProducts = "DELETE FROM products WHERE
```

productID='$deleteold' ";

then update

```
    $sql_quote_add = "SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE bid_name ='$quotename' "; 

    $client_data = $con->query($sql_quote_add);
```

get the id to see if it matches any of the ids submitted

```
   $getquoteid= mysqli_fetch_assoc($client_data);   

    $oldquoteid = $getquoteid['quoteID'];
```

// for this depends how you are submitting it, i am doing it ajax
         for ( $for =0; $for < count($data['productName']); $for++) {
then inside the for lopp
we check if the ids match any of the current products

I exploded an array i had submitted, easiest way i thought of doing it, then just do a count inside so it can loop

```
 if($tagArray[$for] == $pro_old_id){

    $updateold = "UPDATE products SET price='$priceNew', 

   } else
 $sql_bid = sprintf("INSERT INTO products

 }
```